# The scrapy LinkExtractor(allow=(url)) get the wrong crawled page, the regulex doesn't work

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to crawl the page http://www.douban.com/tag/%E7%88%B1%E6%83%85/movie .
And some part of my spider code is :

```
class MovieSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "doubanmovie"
    allowed_domains = ["douban.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.douban.com/tag/%E7%88%B1%E6%83%85/movie"]
    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://www.douban.com/tag/%E7%88%B1%E6%83%85/movie\?start=\d{2}'))),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"http://movie.douban.com/subject/\d+")), callback = "parse_item")
            )

    def start_requests(self):
        yield FormRequest("http://www.douban.com/tag/%E7%88%B1%E6%83%85/movie",headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0'})
```

I only want to crawl the page like "\?start=\d{2}", but the scrapy spider will also crawl the page like "\?start=100" or "\?start=1000". What's wrong with it? How to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `\d{2}` matches every number that starts with two digits.

If you want to limit the regular expression to two digits you can use `\d{2}$` so that it only matches if there are tow digits at the end of the line.

Even more general would be to use `\d{2}\b` so that any non-alphanumeric value or whitespace has to follow.